# Nagios conditional checks

Tags: nagios

Currently I am monitoring my target windows hosts for a bunch of services (CPU, memory, disks, ssl certs, http etc). I'm using nsclient as the client that the nagios server will talk to.

My problem is that I deploy to those hosts three times every 24 hours. The deployment process requires the hosts to reboot. Whenever my hosts reboot I get nagios alerts for each service. This means a large volume of alerts, which makes it difficult to identify real issues.

Ideally I'd like to this:

- If the host is down, don't send any alerts for the rest of the services
- If the host is rebooting, this means that nsclient is not accessible. I want to only receive one alert (e.g CPU is not accessible) and mute everything else for a few minutes, so the host can finish booting and nsclient becomes available.

Implementing this would have me getting one email per host for each deployment. This is much better than everything turning red and me getting flooded with alerts that aren't worth checking (since they're only getting sent because the nagios client -nsclient- is not available during the reboot).

Got to love using a windows stack...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to handle this.
If your deploys happens at the same time everyday:
1. you could modify your active time period to exclude those times (or)
2. schedule down time for your host via the Nagios GUI

If your deployments happen at different/random times, things become a bit harder to work-around:
1. when nrpe or nsclient is not reachable, Nagios will often throw an 'UNKNOWN' alert for the check.  If you remove the 'u' option for the following entries:

```
host_notification_options   [d,u,r,f,s,n]
service_notification_options    [w,u,c,r,f,s,n]
```

That would prevent the 'UNKNOWN's from sending notifications. (or)
2. dynamically modify active checking of the impacted checks, by 'turning them off' before you start the deployment, and then 'turning them on' after the deployment.  This can be automated using the Nagios 'external commands file'.

Answer (score 1):

Jim Black's answer would work, or if you want to go even more in depth you can define dependencies with service notification escalation as described in the documentation below.

Escalating the alerts would mean that you could define: CPU/ssl etc check fail -> check host down -> Notifiy/don't notify.

[Nagios Service Escalation (3.0)](http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/objectdefinitions.html#serviceescalation)

Comment: I would have to disagree.  There are 100's of reasons a 'primary' check can fail, that don't mean a host is actually down.  And failed primary check causes any dependent checks not to run.